# Issues with CSS and JavaScript for creating a carousel with multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a carousel with multiple images using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but I am having trouble getting it to work properly. The first image displays correctly, but the second image only shows up partially or not at all. I have tried adjusting the CSS, but it doesn't seem to be solving the issue.

Here is my current code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const track = document.querySelector('.carousel_track');
    const slides = Array.from(track.children);
    const nextButton = document.querySelector('button.button-carousel.next');
    const prevButton = document.querySelector('button.button-carousel.prev');
    const trackWidth = track.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const slideWidth = trackWidth / slides.length;

    // const setSlide = (slide, index) => {
    //   slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + 'px';
    // };
    const setSlide = (slide, index) => {
        const offset = (track.offsetWidth - slideWidth) / 2;
        slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + offset + 'px';
      };
    slides.forEach(setSlide);

    const moveToSlide = (track, currS, nextS) => {
      track.style.transform = `translateX(-${nextS.style.left})`;
      currS.classList.remove('current-slide');
      nextS.classList.add('current-slide');
    };

    prevButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const currS = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
      const prevS = currS.previousElementSibling || slides[slides.length - 1];
      moveToSlide(track, currS, prevS);
    });

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const currS = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
      let nextS = currS.nextElementSibling;
      if (!nextS) {
        nextS = slides[0];
      }
      moveToSlide(track, currS, nextS);
    });
  });
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel_track {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%; /* Set the width of the carousel_track to be twice the width of one slide */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


.slide {
  position: relative; /* Change the position of the slide to relative */
  display: inline-block; /* Set the display of the slide to inline-block */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: slideWidth;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}


button.button-carousel.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

button.button-carousel.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="carousel">
    <button class="button-carousel prev"><svg width="14.6" height="27" viewBox="0 0 16 27"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M16 23.207L6.11 13.161 16 3.093 12.955 0 0 13.161l12.955 13.161z" fill="#000000"></path>
      </svg></button>
    <button class="button-carousel next"><svg width="14.6" height="27" viewBox="0 0 16 27"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M16 23.207L6.11 13.161 16 3.093 12.955 0 0 13.161l12.955 13.161z" fill="#000000"></path>
      </svg></button>
    <ul class="carousel_track">
      <li class="slide current-slide"><img class="slideimg" src="img1.webp" alt="image"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img class="slideimg" src="img4.webp" alt="image"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue and get the carousel to display all the images properly?

I tried to create a simple carousel with 2 images but right now i am getting only one image to move. i want both the images to move when i click on the next and prev buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This works! I made only a few changes in the css code and changed one line in the Javascript code.

Updated css (deleted some useless and troublesome lines to archive the desidered result):

```css
.carousel {
 height: 600px;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel_track {
 display: flex;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.slide {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 flex: 0 0 auto;
 width: slideWidth;
}
.slide img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}
button.button-carousel.prev {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 50;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: none;
 padding: 30px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
button.button-carousel.next {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 50;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: none;
 padding: 30px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Updated Javascript (line 7):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 const track =  document.querySelector('.carousel_track');
 const slides = Array.from(track.children);
 const nextButton = document.querySelector('button.button-carousel.next');
 const prevButton = document.querySelector('button.button-carousel.prev');
 const trackWidth = track.getBoundingClientRect().width;
 const slideWidth = trackWidth;
 // const setSlide = (slide, index) => {
 // slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + 'px';
 // };
 const setSlide = (slide, index) => {
  const offset = (track.offsetWidth - slideWidth) / 2;
  slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + offset + 'px';
 };
 slides.forEach(setSlide);
 const moveToSlide = (track, currS, nextS) => {
  track.style.transform = `translateX(-${nextS.style.left})`;
  currS.classList.remove('current-slide');
  nextS.classList.add('current-slide');
 };
 prevButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const currS = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
  const prevS = currS.previousElementSibling || slides[slides.length - 1];
  moveToSlide(track, currS, prevS);
 });
 nextButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const currS = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
  let nextS = currS.nextElementSibling; if (!nextS) { nextS = slides[0]; }
  moveToSlide(track, currS, nextS);
 });
});
```

Comment: It's great you've been able to provide assistance and a working answer! However, it would be better for the asker (and future visitors) , if you describe with words and in-code comments what the problem was and what you did to fix it (:

Comment: In your answer, please. Not down here in comments. See [answer].